# How to install redis-server with version 5.0.7 on ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: command-line, apt, server, mongodb, redis

I want to install redis-server with specific version.

Comment: Lately whenever I have needed a specific version of software, I've spun up a Docker container. This allows me to run it on any (recent) version of Ubuntu and I don't have to worry that an `apt update` will break the operation of that software.

Comment: Is it just that specific version or just some newer [version](https://launchpad.net/~redislabs/+archive/ubuntu/redis/+index) of redis-server?

Answer (score 0):

It is not available in that distribution you need 20.04 to get that version 5 of it.

https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=redis-server&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all